# Unity: Local (LAN) MatchMaking error

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unity-networking, unity3d-unet

I'm trying to create a simple Multiplayer game. I have setup a matchmaking system and it works fine while the device is connected with the internet i.e an online lobby is successfully created. But when i try to create a lobby on local network which does not have internet access, nothing happens.

Here is the code that i use for hosting the game:

```
void Start()
{
    netManager = NetworkManager.singleton;
    if(netManager.matchMaker == null)
    {
        netManager.StartMatchMaker();
    }

    roomName = "MyGameRoom";
    roomSize = 12;
}

public void CreateRoom()
{
    if (roomName != "" && roomName != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Creating Room:" + roomName);
        netManager.matchMaker.CreateMatch(roomName, roomSize, true, "", "", "", 0, 0, netManager.OnMatchCreate);
    }
}
```

Now if the device is connected to the internet, the game is hosted successfully. But if the device is connected to a wifi which has no internet service, nothing happens when the `CreateRoom` method is called.

The `CreateRoom()` method is linked with a `onClick` event of a button.

I'm new to unity networking, hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the console when you run the application in the editor, and add an error to the question if there is an error.

Comment: @itay_421 No errors, this is what the console says................ `MatchMakingClient Create :https://mm.unet.unity3d.com/json/reply/CreateMatchRequest
UnityEngine.Networking.Match.NetworkMatch:CreateMatch(String, UInt32, Boolean, String, String, String, Int32, Int32, DataResponseDelegate`1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic MatchMaking service is based on connecting to unity MatchMaker server (https://mm.unet.unity3d.com) and this server is located on the internet, which means you can't connect to It if you are not connected to the internet. The solution is to use the [NetworkDiscovery](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkDiscovery.html) which let your server send broadcast messages over the network so clients can "hear" the broadcast and then connect to the sender. If you want a sample check this [thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/networkdiscovery-sample.354928/).